# Why doesn't the overlay background show?

Tags: theming, media, javascript

I created a fancybox gallery as block using the Views module and inserted that block into the node using the [Insert Block](https://drupal.org/project/insert_block) module. Everything works fine, but the overlay background doesn't show.

How do I fix this?

Edit: The problem has been resolved: The 'Overlay helper' was disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved: The 'Overlay helper' was disabled.